The title property appears to me as a type that does not exist and I don't know what to do?
I am doing a dynamic route with astro and react and when doing a fetch to obtain the array of objects it tells me that the Prduct.title property is never and I don't know why
src/pages/category/[category].astro
---
import type { Product } from "../../types/component.type";
import Layout from "../../layouts/Layout.astro";

export async function getStaticPaths(category: Product) {

    const categoryToSearch = category.id
  const data = await fetch(https://api.escuelajs.co/api/v1/categories/${categoryToSearch}/products).then(response => response.json());

  return data.map((category: Product) => {
    return {
      params: { id: category.id },
      props: { products: data },
    };
  });
}

const { id } = Astro.params;
const { products } = Astro.props;

---

<Layout title={id}>
    <Layout title={id}>
    <section class="py-36">
      {products.map((product: Product) => (
            <h1>{product.title}</h1>
      ))}
    </section>
</Layout>
</Layout>

I get this error:
14:18:16 [WARN] [router] getStaticPaths() ignored in dynamic page /src/pages/category/[category].astro. Add export const prerender = true; to prerender the page as static HTML during the build process.
14:18:17 [200] /category/1 16ms
14:18:17 [ERROR] Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')
  Stack trace:
    at Object.default (C:\Users\facum\modern-ecommerce\src\pages\category\[category].astro:27:17)
    [...] See full stack trace in the browser, or rerun with --verbose.

I would have to return an array of objects to later be able to put together the dynamic route of a product for an e-commerce that I am doing

Add code that shows where this component was used.

You are missing quotes around the string in your fetch. It should be:
const data = await fetch("https://api.escuelajs.co/api/v1/categories/${categoryToSearch}/products")
  .then(response => response.json());


The OP doesn’t call getStaticPaths() so the error is not from there. The error comes from Astro.props.products not being an Array hence doesn’t have a map() method.

@ChukwujiobiCanon ah you're probably right. Feel free to add your own answer...

The OP ought to have more info.

Edit:
In addition to the changes explained below, you also need to figure out the IDs to fetch. You won't receive them from getStaticPath. So you should write something like:
export async function getStaticPaths() {
  const categories = await fetch(`https://api.escuelajs.co/api/v1/categories`).then(response => response.json());

  return await Promise.all(categories.map(async (category: Product) => {
    return {
      params: { category: category.id },
      props: { products: await fetch(`https://api.escuelajs.co/api/v1/categories/${category.id}/products`).then(response => response.json()); },
    };
  }));
}

I didn't test but what you need to do is:

collect all the categories available to retrieve their ids
Map over the categories to collect the associated products

So you need two fetch unless you have another API route that offers you both the ids and the products in a single request.
First answer:
Your getStaticPath function is never called (see the WARN in your console) so your component never receives those props and you can't use map with an undefined variable.
The reason why your getStaticPath is never called is because params mismatches your filename ([category].astro). It should be:
export async function getStaticPaths(category: Product) {

  const categoryToSearch = category.id
  const data = await fetch(`https://api.escuelajs.co/api/v1/categories/${categoryToSearch}/products`).then(response => response.json());

  return data.map((category: Product) => {
    return {
      params: { category: category.id },
      props: { products: data },
    };
  });
}

I replaced params: { id: category.id } with params: { category: category.id }. If you look at Astro documentation you will see that the key used inside params should match your filename (the name inside the brackets).
With those corrections, Astro should execute getStaticPaths since the params is valid and you should now receive your props.

I made the changes and I got the same error. Reading other answers, I think it is because what the api returns is not an array, but thank you very much for your answer.

I just checked the API, https://api.escuelajs.co/api/v1/categories/1/products for example is returning an array. But I didn't notice it before, why do you have category: Product as prop for getStaticPath? The only valid prop is an object receiving a paginate function. You can't receive category.id from it. So if you call your API with categoryToSearch = undefined effectively, you won't receive an array. You need to know in advance the IDs you need to fetch to generate the static paths. I'll update my answer. It might not be the most efficient but it should work.
